# Change cloud service Google to AWS: pain for firewall creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, firewall

I'd like to create a manual firewall in AWS, but I'm a Google Cloud user today.
In Google Cloud in my Ubuntu VM, I code:

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud beta compute firewall-rules create allow-rstudio-server \
    --allow tcp:8787 \
    --target-tags rstudio-server
gcloud compute instances add-tags fc-cmpc-1 --tags rstudio-server
```

Please, any help with the same code for AWS?

Thanks in advance.